# How do I best identify weak points in myself along a path to academia

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I will be graduating from university (in the states) this semester with a bachelors in physics and mathematics. I applied for physics PhD programs (in the states) this cycle and obtained a few admissions. However, I am considering taking another year to improve my application and apply to physics PhD programs again, next cycle.

The problem is, I find it difficult to know what to focus on in terms of improving my application. Hence, I am asking how does one best judge what the weak points of their application is along a road to academia.

Clarification: Even though I am currently at the stage of entering graduate studies, I mean to ask this question for the more general setting of continuing on a path to academia.

Comment: Why did you apply to schools if you wouldn't go there when admitted? Were you offered funding? It sounds like your next step to improve in physics is to accept an offer and do a PhD.

Comment: Why do you need to improve your application and apply to physics PhD programs again next year, if you've already obtained a few admissions?

Comment: Does physics have a tradition of pre-doc RA jobs? That would be the way to get into a higher ranked program in my field, economics.

Comment: @BryanKrause There is also a 2-body problem involved, which makes it (for me) a serious option to apply another cycle.

Comment: @SillyGoose how would applying another cycle help? Are you planning to apply with your partner and only attending a university that accepts you both?

Comment: @Allure I would apply to more schools in the appropriate area and also hopefully improve my application so as to get better results.

Comment: How is it unacceptable that you got admitted already? Are any of those schools acceptable? Or all unacceptable?

Comment: So you didn't have a 2-body problem in November/December but do now that it's March? I know that's quite possible but do think carefully about decisions that will affect you for at least the next 5 years and possibly indefinitely.

Comment: "How do I best identify weak points in myself" – " what to focus on in terms of improving my application." These are two very different things. You can certainly do things to improve *yourself* (i.e., you can self-study). It is, however, highly doubtful that you can do anything to improve *your application* on your own (unless you have publications in the pipeline that can realistically be accepted before the next round of applications). What matters on PhD applications are tangible and verifiable facts, not your own assertion that you studied really hard all year to improve yourself.

Comment: @BryanKrause: it is not as simple as "schools I don't want to go" and "schools I want to go". There are "schools that are not great but would be acceptable". The OP is just pondering if improving his skills would land him in a better school. It is the same when you look for housing or for a job.

Comment: @Taladris Exactly: if they are acceptable then you go there when they admit you and other schools you rank higher don't.

Comment: @BryanKrause: you can rent/buy the first acceptable apartment you find. But if you can, you can also wait some time until you find your dream apartment. Same for a job, a PhD program, etc.

Comment: @Taladris You have to live somewhere, and there's an application calendar. So you apply to every apartment you might be willing to live in, and accept the best one that accepts you. If there's a dump you'd never live in even if they accepted you, you just don't apply. Grad school isn't like apartments where new ones open up from time to time: all the schools are there and they need you to apply at about the same time (typically in the US; of course there are some schools and some countries where rolling admissions happen, etc).

Comment: Now if something comes up that makes you decide a program you thought would be a good fit actually isn't (maybe you get a really bad one when visiting, maybe the professor(s) you hoped to work with aren't taking students) it's reasonable to not accept that offer, but OP described multiple accepted offers.

Comment: Your plan doesn’t sounds like a good idea. You can become better only by moving ahead in your academic journey as soon as you can, have PhD degree and start a faculty position. There is no definition of what is enough and what is not in your personal journey. It’s terrible idea to define “enough” looking at others when you are living your own journey by yourself. My suggestion is to accept position if you like and move ahead if you are already accepted.

Comment: @BryanKrause: you may live with your parents, stay at a friend's place, etc, until you find your dream apartment. If the OP does not choose to enroll in a program that accepts him, he will not be in a sort of limbo doing anything: he may choose to improve his skills, get a job (to get money to attend a better program?), etc

Comment: I think @Taladris 's original comment is what I had in mind. I also intended to do an RA in the interim year (for more research experience and a livable wage). I see it as: one extra year is really inconsequential in the big picture. I am surprised that more people do not see the perspective as presented by Taladris.

Comment: I agree with @Taladris (please write up your comment as an answer BTW), but I can understand the other perspectives as there is definitely an "age limit" for some stuff in academia, especially in more experimental disciplines. Universities also prefer to hire younger faculty for their first PI position.

Comment: There can be schools that you applied to as safeties with your partner, but since you both got into better schools, the safeties become a bad option that was only ever a back up to begin with. I think what OP might be thinking of is closer to "my partner and I applied to grad school together. I got into a few safeties, and they got into their top choice. I'm considering doing an RA in their region to apply to schools in that city so that I can both be near them and have a chance at getting into a better program", which is exponentially better than living alone at a safety school. @BryanKrause

Answer (score 21):

You say that you "obtained ***a few*** [i.e., more that one] admissions"! Unless you deliberately applied only for schools that you thought were extremely weak in the belief that no stronger school would accept you, it is not at all clear what it would mean to "improve" your application. Clearly more than one school thought you were a good candidate.

My advice ... choose the school that seems like the best fit, and accept! It sounds (which might not reflect the reality of your experience, of course) as if the main problem is simply your self-confidence.

Answer (score 9):

While I don't understand why you would give up acceptance and spend another year, likely without support, I'll try to answer your direct question and give a bit of advice.

You can identify weaknesses by asking one of your professors, who presumably has gone through the system to get a doctorate as well as experience in academia in your field to evaluate your application and give you general feedback on your suitability for both graduate study and academia.

You are unlikely, though it is possible, to have enough self awareness to be able to do it on your own. Someone who doesn't know you is less likely to be able to give more than general advice ("Take this course. Take that course."). Ask someone who knows you and your work. Someone you trust. Someone who will be honest.

The advice, which I think you've already taken if I read it correctly, is to accept the best offer you've gotten and live with that decision. Presumably you applied to institutions that would be acceptable to you for study. Taking a year away is likely to set you back, since it puts you a year out from close contact with faculty letter writers and leaves you with little, if any, actual guidance. Those letter writers are essential in the US and they are likely to be better when the memory of the writer is fresh.

Take a year away only if you have no other options. It seems, to me, to be the worst option of all. It would be different if you'd suggested that you had a way to keep in close contact and do some important work and get some important feedback and make some important contacts and, and, and.... But you aren't suggesting that.

Answer (score 9):

Well, you are at such an early stage of your career that the weakest point in yourself is being "outside" of academia, and it seems you are deliberately putting yourself outside by rejecting PhD positions you were accepted for.

So that is the only point you can reasonably work on. Accept one of these positions and then work out your path from there.
If the biggest problem is a 2-body problem, as a PhD you will manage it by a mixture of strategically placed workshops, remote working hours... and living frugally to afford planes to move around (you are in the US, so you are bound to use these 20th century technological marvels, which is better than nothing).

Answer (score 0):

"Weakest point" is relative. It depends upon the context. Do not fall into trap of reputation of an institute or your exam score or some people suggest you otherwise. Be clear to yourself about how much you are interested in the subject; and whether the institute you choose, has a way of teaching and other system that suits you.

I often find that I do terrible in courses or institutes that does not offer me with lot of time to think and library work.

I often do wonderful when a course or institute provides more time to self prepare, flexibility to choose time for library work, and there are places for correcting or making improvements from the past bad performances.

I need a lot of alone time and quite space, not bothered by people.

Even when I am outside campus, I keep thinking of what has been taught and what other concepts it relate with.

In the flip side I know several people who do not know how to self study. Whatever their teachers teach them, they just memorize that in a linear fashion, they do not make any bad performances in any of the terms, but given that there are scope of improvement applying past knowledge, they cannot apply and improve. Yet they can easily cope up with abrupt changes. When one teacher exits and the next teacher enters, they do not need a fraction of second to prepare themselves. They can multitask, they can listen to the class lecture and take notes at the same time. Most of them are social butterfly, and continuously need social stimulation.

Now most definitely, an institute which will favor me, will NOT favor the second type. Whereas an institute which will favor the second type, will NOT favor me. And up to my observation, the second type is usually the preferred type of students in my locale. Even when there are policy or system that favors the first type; the second type starts various criticism and protest so that the system shifts into the favor of the second type.

That is why I do not do great in regular courses, but I tend to do better with  distance and vocational courses where they leave their students for most of the time. Sometimes I find that charitable institutes offer very good library facility with easy and simultaneous access to books, lending books to home, which is more suitable for me than regular courses.